# Should this class implement ICollection, IList, List or neither?

Tags: c#, list, collections

I am trying to create a class which has a collection of items that expire (removed from the collection) after some defined `TimeSpan`; I realize that if I do not actively remove the items some might expire and still be in the collection.

So far I cannot decide how I should implement this class. I am not sure whether I should implement `ICollection`, `IList`, subclass `List`, or wrap `List`?

```
public struct EDLItem<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public EDLItem(T data) : this()
    {
        Data = data;
        Created = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Boolean IsExpired(TimeSpan lifetime)
    {
        TimeSpan lifeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Created);
        return TimeSpan.Compare(lifeSpan, lifetime) == 1;
    }
}

public class ExpiringDataList1<T> : ICollection<EDLItem<T>>{}

public class ExpiringDataList2<T> : IList<EDLItem<T>>{}

public class ExpiringDataList3<T> : List<EDLItem<T>>{}

public class ExpiringDataList<T>
{
    public TimeSpan DataLifetime { get; set; }
    private List<EDLItem<T>> DataList { get; set; }

    public ExpiringDataList(TimeSpan dataLifetime)
    {
        DataLifetime = dataLifetime;
        DataList = new List<EDLItem<T>>();
    }

    public void CheckExperiations()
    {
        DataList.RemoveAll(item => item.IsExpired(DataLifetime));
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        DataList.Add(new EDLItem<T>(item));
        CheckExperiations();
    }
}
```

My plan is to check/remove items that have expired whenever an item is added to the collection or when the collection is iterated over (prior to an `IENumerable` being gotten for the collection).

What choice should I make for this implementation?

Comment: 1) No, don't extend any of these classes. If it makes sense to implement `IList` methods, do, but I am presuming it would be a broken contract. 2) Use the existing `MemoryCache` class. 3) If nothing else, use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @juharr: I agree, but for reference types it shouldn't make a performance impact (and I don't think people need to cache structs too often). It's also thread safe, which is usually a nice thing to have with caches.

Comment: Completely opinion based question... Since we don't know what are use cases for your class there is no way to suggest what would be better. The only one I would cross out is directly deriving from `List` - as you have to override all methods anyway to check for expiration. Note also that indexing of IList items is generally expected to be O(1), so if that is important operation you'd have to do some extensive optimizations to avoid O(n) cost of `CheckExperiations()` on each access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some advice:

- In general, prefer composition to inheritance.
- Do not extend `List<T>` unless you are building a new list abstraction, and even then, probably not.  It sounds like you actually *are* building such an abstraction, which most people who ask about extending List are not.  In that case, ask yourself two questions: (1) do I need the underlying mechanisms of a list, and (2) will anyone be using this thing polymorphically?  See the next point.
- Interfaces exist to enable polymorphism. Consider whether a client will use your class polymorphically with other unrelated classes when deciding whether to implement an interface. Is anyone *ever* going to want to sort, search, filter or join on your thing? Then implement `IEnumerable<T>`. Is anyone going to pass it to a method that takes an `IList<T>`?  Then implement that.  But this decision should be driven by the *customer requirements*, not by what you could possibly implement.